# Usage of springcache plugin in grails

Tags: caching, grails, service, aspectj, ehcache

I've been trying to add SpringCache to one of my Spring-managed services. I'm using STS as my development IDE.

Here is what I did:

1. Installed springcache 1.3.1 plugin
2. Added cache configuration to Config.groovy:

   ```
   grails.spring.disable.aspectj.autoweaving = true

   springcache {
     enabled = true
     defaults {
         eternal = false
         diskPersistent = false
     }
     caches {
         tripCache {
             memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = "LRU"
         }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Added `@Cacheable` annotation above my test method in the service as follows:

   ```
     int counter = 0

     @Cacheable("testCache")
     String testInc(String x) {
       return (++counter).toString()
     }
   ```
4. Now, I'm calling this method from the controller as follows:

   ```
     def testDashboard() {
       [data:testService.testInc("1")]
     }
   ```

And `testInc()` always returns me a new value, i.e. successive calls return 1, 2, 3, etc. which makes me think that caching isn't working. Did I miss something and didn't turn on the caching properly?

I tried to see if caching is working at all and I hooked the source-code for ehcache-2.4.6 and setup breakpoints in the invokeCachedMethod of the CachingAspect, but when I run my app the above method doesn't seem to be executed.

I've also tried to see the value of "1" inside of the cache and looks like it's null, i.e. key "1" isn't getting stored in the cache. I added the following two lines to the controller test method:

```
      Ehcache c = springcacheService.getOrCreateCache("testCache")
      String x = c.get("1")
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I was misleaded by reading documentation of springcache here:
http://gpc.github.com/grails-springcache/docs/guide/3.%20Caching%20Service%20Methods.html

`Config.groovy` should have `grails.spring.disable.aspectj.autoweaving = false` isntead of `true`.

Hope this helps to those who got stuck on the same issue.